# How to split a directory string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux, windows, string

In ruby, I'm able to do

```
File.dirname("/home/gumby/bigproject/now_with_bugs_fixed/32/FOO_BAR_2096.results")
```

and get

```
"/home/gumby/bigproject/now_with_bugs_fixed/32"
```

but now I'd like to split up that directory string into the individual folder components, ie something like

```
["home", "gumby", "bigproject", "now_with_bugs_fixed", "32"]
```

Is there a way to do that other than using

```
directory.split("/")[1:-1]
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's no built-in function to split a path into its component directories like there is to join them, but you can try to fake it in a cross-platform way:

```
directory_string.split(File::SEPARATOR)
```

This works with relative paths and on non-Unix platforms, but for a path that starts with `"/"` as the root directory, then you'll get an empty string as your first element in the array, and we'd want `"/"` instead.

```
directory_string.split(File::SEPARATOR).map {|x| x=="" ? File::SEPARATOR : x}
```

If you want just the directories without the root directory like you mentioned above, then you can change it to select from the first element on.

```
directory_string.split(File::SEPARATOR).map {|x| x=="" ? File::SEPARATOR : x}[1..-1]
```

Comment: Note that on Windows File::SEPERATOR is /, not \. So if you only use that method on the result of File.join, it will work fine, but if you want to work with user input or other sources that could use \ as a file seperator you should do something like `dir.split(Regexp.union(*[File::SEPARATOR, File::ALT_SEPARATOR].compact))` (or a more readable version of that)

Comment: Sorry to spam, but this solution is indisputably better: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21572944/924109

Answer (score 46):

The correct answer is to use Ruby's `Pathname` (in-built class since 1.8.7, not a gem).

See the code:

```
require 'pathname'

def split_path(path)
    Pathname(path).each_filename.to_a
end
```

Doing this will discard the information whether the path was absolute or relative. To detect this, you can call `absolute?` method on `Pathname`.

Source: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.3/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html

Comment: I agree to use Pathname.  we can write with tap method as follows too: `[].tap{|x| Pathname.new("/home/gumby/bigproject/now_with_bugs_fixed/32").each_filename{|d| x << d}}`

Comment: It is worth noting that `File.join(Pathname(path).each_filename.to_a) != path` in case of absolute path.

Comment: @x-yuri: To check whether the path is absolute, use the `absolute?` method on `Pathname`.

Answer (score 7):

Rake provides a split_all method added to FileUtils.  It's pretty simple and uses File.split:

```
def split_all(path)
  head, tail = File.split(path)
  return [tail] if head == '.' || tail == '/'
  return [head, tail] if head == '/'
  return split_all(head) + [tail]
end

taken from rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb
```

The rake version has slightly different output from Rudd's code.  Rake's version ignores multiple slashes:

```
irb(main):014:0> directory_string = "/foo/bar///../fn"
=> "/foo/bar///../fn"
irb(main):015:0> directory_string.split(File::SEPARATOR).map {|x| x=="" ? File::SEPARATOR : x}[1..-1]
=> ["foo", "bar", "/", "/", "..", "fn"]
irb(main):016:0> split_all directory_string
=> ["/", "foo", "bar", "..", "fn"]
irb(main):017:0>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Warning: This solution is no longer the best one. See my other one.**

Actually, there is a more neat solution. The main idea is to keep popping the basename until you are only left with the `.` or `/` .

```
def split_path(path)
    array = []
    until ['/', '.'].include? path
        array << File.basename(path)
        path = File.dirname(path)
    end
    array.reverse
end

split_path 'a/b/c/d' #=> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

You can further build upon this idea, if you wish.

Comment: Not simple, neat, or idiomatic.  Avoid.

Comment: @devdanke: Do you need a magnifier for the warning in the first line of the answer?

Comment: Just magnifying the inadequate disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```rb
File.split( "/home/gumby/bigproject/now_with_bugs_fixed/32/FOO_BAR_2096.results").first
=> "/home/gumby/bigproject/now_with_bugs_fixed/32"
```