# How can I get a string between two characters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

Okay if I have a string that is a full file path like `"Folder/New Folder/test.csv"`.  How can I get everything between the `/'s`?  So get `"New Folder"`.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370988/does-ruby-have-the-ability-to-split-a-directory-string , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169923/parsing-string-pathname-with-ruby

Answer (score 3):

No need to use a regex at all...

```
> File.basename(File.dirname("Folder/New Folder/test.csv"))
=> "New Folder"
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily have to use a regex to accomplish this task.

**String Split**

```
path = "Folder/New Folder/test.csv"
puts path.split('/')[1]
```

**File Operations**

```
path = File.dirname("Folder/New Folder/test.csv")
puts File.basename(path)
```

**Regex**

```
path = "Folder/New Folder/test.csv"
puts path.scan(/\/(.*)\//)[0]
```

Using any of these ways, you will get the following output:

```
#=> New Folder
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do

```
File.dirname( "Folder/New Folder/test.csv" ).split('/')[-1]
# => "New Folder"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use regex:

```
input = "Folder/New Folder/test.csv"
print input.scan(/\/(.*)\//).flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using a regular expression. Note this will yield whatever is between the 1st and 2nd `/`. So if your String would be `"some/longer/path/than/original"`, it would yield `"longer"`.

```
path = "Folder/New Folder/test.csv"
p path[%r{/([^/]+)/}, 1]
# => "New Folder"
```

Comment: I feel jealous on you, as you are so good in *Regex*.. I am not. :p